# If $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\le\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}$, $\sum_nb_n$ converges $\implies$ $\sum_na_n$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Let $\{a_n\},\{b_n\}$ be positive sequences satisfying $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\le\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n},\ \forall n\in\Bbb N$. Suppose that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ converges. Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ also converges.

I'm not sure how to go about proving this, I think I need to use the comparison test or the ratio test, or a combination of both in order to prove convergence of an.

Comment: Please format your math with MathJax. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n > 0, b_n > 0$, for all $n \geq N$. We have  $$\frac{a_{n+N}}{a_n} = \prod_{i=1}^N \frac{a_{n+i}}{a_{n+i-1}} \leq \prod_{i=1}^N \frac{b_{n+i}}{b_{n+i-1}} = \frac{b_{n+N}}{b_{n}}$$. Look at tail sum: $\sum_{N=1}^{\infty} a_{n+N} \leq \frac{a_n}{b_n} \times \sum_{N=1}^{\infty} b_{n+N} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ since summation of ${b_n}$ converges and $\frac{a_n}{b_n}$ is bounded since $\frac{a_{n+1}}{b_{n+1}} \leq \frac{a_n}{b_n}$.

Answer (score 0):

We have,
\begin{equation*}
a_n = a_1 \prod_{ j = 1}^{ n -1 } \frac{ a_{k+1} }{ a_k } \leq a_1 \prod_{ j = 1}^{ n -1 } \frac{ b_{k+1} }{ b_k } = \frac{ a_1 }{ b_1 } b_n 
\end{equation*}
for any $ n \geq 1 $. Thus the series $ \sum_{ n =1 }^{\infty} a_{n } $ converges by comparison test.